# Visual Studio Schema Compare repeats table on update

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

When comparing our production database to our database project, one table always shows up as "Add" action, even though the file is already part of the project. Updating the schema then produces the same file again with an underscore and increment (dbo.Data.sql => dbo.Data_1.sql)

I noticed that when I open the individual table creation scripts, all scripts open in `[Design]` mode while the offending table opens as plain T-SQL.

How do I add `topsheet.Data` to my project without it showing up on my next schema compare?

- The offending table: `topsheet.Data`
- A normal table: `topsheet.Property`

[image: Schema Compare Picture]

Comment: Does it do this if you rename the table Data to something else?  [I saw here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822(v=sql.105).aspx) that Data is a future reserved keyword, maybe this is making it act all weird?

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. You are absolutely right. I tried using "data" as a field name and it didn't mark it blue so I thought it would be okay. I renamed the table and now it compares correctly. Wow. Please submit this as the answer, I will mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it do this if you rename the table Data to something else? [I saw here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that Data is a future reserved keyword, maybe this is making it act all weird?